# Displaying a UI after clicking a button

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a new UI within another UI which should be displayed on clicking a button using Java Swing. What should I do?

In my program on clicking next button I need to display a new UI. How can I link the new ui to the already existing one?

Comment: Can you give an example? Do you mean something like an [assistant](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGInstallationsUpdates/XHIGInstallationsUpdates.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002722-TPXREF23)?

Comment: An UI within a UI? You'll need a very powerful sedative! (I'm sorry, I couldn't help it :) )

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean wizard like? You can place all your UIs in CardLayout and switch them. Or remove old and add new calling

```
container.revalidate();
container.repaint();
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to make the second UI not visible from the start.

```
setVisible(false);
```

and when you click the button make it visible:

```
setVisible(true);
```